# How to order an array of arrays by index in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to order an array of arrays by it's 2nd index, so if I have something like:

```
a[0][0] = #
a[0][1] = $
a[1][0] = x
a[1][1] = y
a[1][2] = z
a[2][0] = qaz
a[2][1] = qwerty
```

I get:

```
a[0][0] = #
a[1][0] = x
a[2][0] = qaz
a[0][1] = $
a[1][1] = y
a[2][1] = qwerty
a[1][2] = z
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you know the `sort()` function?

Comment: OK, so what have you tried? This site is not for other people to write all your code for you.

Comment: I know the sort function but doesn´t that sort it by value instead of by index???

Comment: @linker85 Do you know that the `sort` function takes an optional argument which is a function that allows you to do custom sorting?

Comment: Are you actually trying to sort, or just loop through the arrays and output the values?

Comment: Are you *sure* the example data are correct?  Because they do not show a "sort by 2nd value", they show "sort a series of 3 arrays lockstep with 2nd array".

Comment: The two examples you gave are equivalent, just with the elements in a different order. What do you intend to do with this 'sorted' array?

Comment: i´m trying to sort because in reality the value of my arrays are going to be html so i need to to be able to sort them by index instead of by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will display the elements in the required order.

```
var a = [["#", "$"], ["x", "y", "z"], ["qaz", "qwerty"]]
var maxLen = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, a[i].length);
}
for (var y = 0; y < maxLen; y++)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < a.length; x++)
    {
        if (y < a[x].length)
        {
            alert(a[x][y]); // You could use document.write() etc.
        }
    }
}
```

You didn't say what you intend to do with the array elements, but this general idea will work for displaying or printing them in order.

Comment: You can also use this technique to insert the elements into a new array that will preserve the sort order that you need.